# Adjoint of a differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am self-studying differential equations using MIT's publicly available materials.  One of the recitation exercises runs as follows:

Define an inner or dot product on $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$ by 
    \begin{align}
 \langle u, v \rangle & = \int_a^bu(x)v(x)dx
 \end{align}
    Suppose $L[u] = u'' + pu' + qu$ is a differential operator, and $M[u]$ is its adjoint.  Show that $\langle L[u], v\rangle = \langle u, M[v]\rangle$ for all $u, v \in \mathcal{C}^2[a,b]$ provided $u(a) = u(b) = v(a) = v(b) = 0$.

In neither the textbook nor the lecture notes has the notion of an adjoint been introduced, so I went to Wikipedia (and various other online sources) for a definition.  From what I can tell,  if $T$ is a differential operator, then its adjoint $T^*$ is defined as the differential operator such that 
\begin{align}
\langle Tu, v \rangle = \langle u,T^*v\rangle
\end{align}

But if this is the case, isn't what the exercise asks for true immediately and trivially?  (And, moreover, independent of the fact that $u(a) = u(b) = v(a) = v(b) = 0$?)

No doubt there's something basic I don't know.  If so, a gentle hint (rather than a complete solution) would be appreciated.

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ constants?

Comment: Yes -- not only are they constants, they are real.

Comment: They probably mean the [formal adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator#Formal_adjoint_in_one_variable).

Comment: I think two approaches: Find explicit form for $M$ or proof that adjoint of $L$ exists

Comment: @A.P.  Sorry -- didn't see the link.  I'll try that.  Thank you.  If it works, I'll mention it here, and you can put it in an answer to get the reputation reward.

Comment: @A.P. Your suggestion was correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the definition of the [formal adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator#Formal_adjoint_in_one_variable), we have $M[u] := u'' - pu' + qu$. We verify the adjoint relation as follows:

$$\begin{align}\langle L[u],v\rangle &=\int_a^b(u''(x) + pu'(x) + qu(x))v(x)dx \\ &= \int_a^b u''(x)v(x)dx + p\int_a^bu'(x)v(x)dx + q\int_a^b u(x)v(x)dx \\ &= \int_a^b u(x)v''(x)dx - p\int_a^bu(x)v'(x)dx + q\int_a^b u(x)v(x)dx\\&= \int_a^bu(x)(v''(x)-pv'(x)+qu(v))dx \\&= \int_a^b u(x) M[v](x)dx \\ &= \langle u,M[v]\rangle\end{align}$$

where on the third line we used integration by parts (twice on the first term and once on the second) and the fact that $u$ and $v$ vanish on the boundary.